# How to access extract contacts from outlook using C++ dynamically on all versions

Tags: c++, com, outlook

I would like to extract data from from outlook(mainly contacts) using C++. I have already found ways to do it in : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3695/Importing-contacts-from-Outlook?msg=3005747#xx3005747xx

But here the import statements are hard-coded : #import "E:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Office10\mso.dll"

Is it possible to dynamically load the dlls and tlb files and use it so that the software could work in different versions of outlook and windows. ( currently by hardcoding i'm not able to access different versions of outlook, since the path is different)

Comment: How about using old fashioned [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with [GetProcAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: @mvp : I checked Loadlibrary but i'm confused on using GetProcAddress along with the code present in this link : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3695/Importing-contacts-from-Outlook?msg=3005747#xx3005747xx , there was also the problem of importing the .tlb file which was required.Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Importing a DLL like this does not mean you're linking in any way to the DLL in question. It just means it will import the Type Library the DLL contains. The Type Library will describe the COM component you want to use: interfaces, coclasses, guids, iids, enums, etc.

At runtime when you instantiate a COM class, COM will create an instance of it from the component that is marked as [the one that serves it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683835.aspx). So in the Office case, if you have installed only Office 14 for example, Office 14 will be marked as the COM server for this class and you don't even know what DLL will in fact be loaded.

Even if you hardcode the version of the Office Type Library you're relying on, it should work with the subsequent versions of Office, because COM relies on binary contracts that should never change.

Of course if you import the Office 10 library, you won't be able to use say Office 14 newer components.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. I'll check your idea. I kind of thought it loads the whole dll. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pointing #import to a file, provide the class name or the type library GUID.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6(v=vs.71).aspx